# Need to add code to the form tag in gravity forms wordpress plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am using the wordpress plugin called "gravity forms", and I need to add the following code to my `<form>` tag. I don't know how to do it seeing as I have very basic php and javascripts skills.

```
oninput="amount.value=rangeInput.value; amount2.value=rangeInput2.value;"
```

My form tag should look like this:

```
<form oninput="amount.value=rangeInput.value; amount2.value=rangeInput2.value;">
```

I assume gravity forms doesn't have a built in solution to do that, so can anyone give me advice on how I can do this through functions.php? or some other way...

Answer (score 0):

Easy to do with some jQuery:

```
$( document ).ready(function() 
{
   $('#gform_1').attr("oninput", "amount.value=rangeInput.value; amount2.value=rangeInput2.value;");
});
```

Make sure that you use the correct ID of your gravity form, `#gform_1` is just an example

Comment: Thank you so much for replying... seems to be what I need... I'm unable to get it to work though.... I added your code to a <script> tag and placed it at the bottom of my page (above the body tag), and edited the id to be the same as my gravity forms form. Not working... Does it matter where on the page I'm adding it? And yes, my jquery library is included on my page...

Comment: your jQuery might be conflicting, try using jQuery instead of $

Jquery( document )... and Jquery('#gform_1')...